# Proactively control div that will be created from the server side

Tags: vue.js

I will expect <div class ="fromLibrary> to be created from a library's js file.

So I want to add a behavior on my client so that it watches the div with "fromLibrary" being created and add a styling to it dynamically?

I can go on node_module and change the specific .js file but library will get constantly updated and will overwrite what I modified.

Does that technique exist or am I being funny.

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: What sort of styles are you trying to apply to it? If you are just trying to style it then writing a css ruleset with an appropriate selector might be enough for this.

Comment: @WillD Trying to put style="white-Space: nowrap;" to a class and append it next to futureClass

Comment: So, you may not need to append a class to it if you can accurately target the element through some sort of specific CSS selector. For example if the div that is created has "fromLibrary" as a classname on it because the library adds that class, then you may be able to just use that class `.fromLibrary { white-Space: nowrap; )`

Comment: It would help if perhaps you post some example code from your DOM (html tree chunk) once the library has created the div.